# filter function doesnt rerender in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've building a page where it get a list of array of object from the server, and I have few checkbox as filter, user will check or uncheck the checkbox, I will have to filter the list, but I have problem rerender the list now. Below is my partial code.

```
filterItem () => {
   // logic goes here
   console.log(filteredItems)

}

renderItems (items) => {
  return(
     //map logic goes here
  )
}

render(){
   return(
      {this.renderItems(this.props.item)}
   )
}
```

how can I rerender renderItems function by passing the `filteredItems` as param to it? I tried `this.renderItems(filteredItems)` but did not see my list got updated.

Comment: Since you use `redux` (according to your comment under the answer) and get all the data in `props` you should `dispatch` an `action` when user toggles a checkbox to get the `state` updated with already filtered items.

Comment: Please, consider updating your question with all the details (like using `redux`) because no one can guess them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `items` in state of component

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        items: this.props.items
    }
}
```

and render it with `{this.renderItems(this.state.items)}`. If i'm clear understand you, and when user click checkbox you filter and change your `items` array, will enough just `setState` this new array, and your component will rerender self.

Answer (score 0):

The props or the state of your component does not change, so your component won't get re-rendered. You probably want to use state (See docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)) to store your data and change it accordingly so that your component will re-render.

Comment: nah, it's props because I use redux. The `items` is from `const { items } = this.props`

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

> An update can be caused by changes to props or state.

You are not doing either